# Getting stuck on opening screen with Lenovo Ideapad

Tags: laptop

I am having a persistent problem with my Lenovo Ideapad. When I switch on the laptop the screen will load but not move on to the password prompt which leaves me no option but to switch the machine off and restart. This is far from ideal as it closes all the apps I may have been using and files I might have been working with.

Is there a way to bypass this using controls? This is not a lost password issue, it is a not being able to insert my password issue.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot fix a problem like this by shutting off outcomes. Look in Task Manager (right click Task Bar), Startup Items and see if you are starting something you do not need. Winkey +R and msconfig,exe  .  Boot tab, set for minimal boot and see if the machine starts correctly. Go from there.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure this answers my question but perhaps I didn't explain it properly. I am not seeking to fix the problem by shutting off the laptop - it is simply the only way in which I can get it to let me log on again properly. So what I was looking for was a way in which I might carry on to the password prompt when the laptop will not move beyond the opening image.

Comment: The second part of my answer provided some methodology to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: It starts correctly like 95% of the time.

Comment: Maybe it is nothing to worry about and future Lenove driver and Windows Updates will fix it.